# Flatten list of json objects into table with column for each object in Databricks

Tags: python, json, databricks

I have a json file that looks like this

```
[
{"id": 1, 
"properties":[{"propertyname":"propertyone",
              "propertyvalye": 5},
              "propertyname":"properttwo",
              "propertyvalye": 7}]},
{"id": 2, 
"properties":[{"propertyname":"propertyone",
              "propertyvalye": 3},
              "propertyname":"properttwo",
              "propertyvalye": 8}]}]
```

I was able load the file in databricks and parse it, getting a column called properties that contains the array in the data. The next step is to flatten this column and get one column for each object in the array with the name from property name and the value. Is there any native way of doing this in databricks?

Most json structures I have worked with in the past are of a `{name:value}` format which is straightforward to parse but the format i'm dealing with is giving me some headaches.
Any suggestions? I would prefer to to use inbuilt functionality, but if there is a way of doing it in python i can also write an UDF

EDIT
This is the output I am looking for.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the sample data to storage:

```
data = """
{"id": 1, "properties":[{"propertyname":"propertyone","propertyvalue": 5},{"propertyname":"propertytwo","propertyvalue": 7}]},
{"id": 2, "properties":[{"propertyname":"propertyone","propertyvalue": 3}, 
{"propertyname":"propertytwo","propertyvalue": 8}]}
 """

dbutils.fs.put(inputpath + "/x.json", data, True)
```

Read the json data:

```
df = spark.read.format("json").load(inputpath)
```

The resultset will look like:

[image]

```
    dfe = df.select("id", explode("properties").alias("p")) \
        .select("id", "p.propertyname", "p.propertyvalue")
```

Will explode the array:

[image]

Finally with pivot, you get the key-value-pairs as columns:

```
display (dfe.groupby('id').pivot('propertyname').agg({'propertyvalue': 'first'}))
```

[image]

See also examples in this [Notebook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/_static/notebooks/transform-complex-data-types-python.html) how to implement transformations on complex datatypes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have added an edit with the output I am looking for. What i ended up doing is writing a python udf that formats the content to how I like it. If i receive no other alternatives I will post that later as an answer. My current issue is that the number of properties can vary anywhere between 10-30 and are subject to change so I am looking at a dynamic way of generating the select query.

Comment: I updated my answer, pivot will do the trick, hope this helps

Comment: This did the trick. I had to add a small udf to "jsonify" the column since this data is present as a column in a much larger table.